# Is is possible to spoof a session with JavaScript + Cookies?

Tags: javascript, security, http, authentication

Suppose you have a webapp that gives users their own site on a subdomain (eg: `awesome.super-cms.com`) and that you let them edit HTML.  Further assume that you're setting the SessionID in a wildcard subdomain cookie ("`*.super-cms.com`").

The user who manages `evil.super-cms.com` could easily write a JavaScript that grabs the SessionID from other super-cms.com users:

```
var session = $.cookie('SessionID');
// Now send `session` to evil.com
```

My question is:  **Could an attacker user these harvested SessionIDs to do bad things?**  For example, spoof authentication as another user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can. This guy appears to have an article outlining examples: http://skeptikal.org/2009/11/cross-subdomain-cookie-attacks.html

You can set the domain of the cookie to prevent this. It is set as `;domain=...` inside the cookie, your given language will probably have a facility to do this directly.

Comment: Thanks.  We're using Django, which allows you to set a SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to do this.  An unfortunate situation, however, because we were really hoping to keep users authenticated across subdomains.

Comment: Kyle: You can still do the authentication across domains, but just with a little bit more work (ensure all links to other domains contain a special querystring, and then validate that appropriately (it's more complicated then this, but that's the general idea, or at least something similar)). What you *don't* want, is them accessing each others cookies.

Answer (score 0):

> Could an attacker user these harvested SessionIDs to do bad things?

Yes, but its a no-brainer to prevent this:

- don't use wildcard cookies
- set the http only flag on any cookies

I assume that you're running this on top of SSL (otherwise its already wide open to MITM attacks) in which case, setting the SSL only flag is a good idea too.

Note that you can't rely on the client ip address not changing (some ISPs use load-balanced proxies) mid session, but the browser headers don't change - however thats not going to help in an attack from someone who knows what they are doing.

C.